# In flutter to display warning popup message

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two classes first class is WidgetManager and second class is Table.
WidgetManager class receives server messages when I receive message like LT|30 then I need to display warning popup message this logic is available in Table class how can I call from WidgetManager class to Table class to display popup message in flutter.

How can I slove that.

Comment: You can achieve this in different ways. If you are using bloc or any other state management, you can emit the state. Or if you initialize the WidgetManager inside the Table class, you can pass the displayPopup function to the WidgetManager class and call the function when you receives messages. If you need further details, please submit  your method or code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.